# Object defined error - copying range till the last row of information

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open a workbook and then select and copy a range from A7 to L7 until the last row of information (in a downward direction). I think the variable isn't properly defined. Any help?

```
Sub Subtotals()
Dim DT As Workbook
Dim lRowDT As Integer


Set DT = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ricardo\Desktop\Data Fuel.xls")
lRowDT = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("Data Fuel.xls").Worksheets("Data").Activate
Worksheets("Data").Range("A7:L" & lRowDT).Copy

End sub
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: lRowDT = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: I don't suppose the `ActiveSheet` after opening the "Data Fuel.xls" workbook is a `Chart`, is it?

Comment: Try `Dim lRowDT As Long`. always use long for your variables, never use `Integer` in VBA unless you have a very special reason.

Comment: It's not a chart YowE3K.

Comment: I tried as long as well but gives me the same error

Comment: I simply don't get it. This is so frustrating sometimes.

Comment: On lRowDT It is giving me =0 and on Rows.Count=1048576. But I don't know why.

Comment: Also he is opening the document correctly but he doesn't select what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is not data over colums L , then this code is suitable.

```
Sub Subtotals()
Dim DT As Workbook
Dim lRowDT As Integer
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngDB As Range, r As Long, c As Long

    Set DT = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ricardo\Desktop\Data Fuel.xls")
    'lRowDT = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Ws = Workbooks("Data Fuel.xls").Worksheets("Data")
    With Ws
        r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        c = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set rngDB = .Range("a7", .Cells(r, "L"))
    End With
    rngDB.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: There´s data on column L as well on A, and in between.

Comment: I have data on A,B,C,H,I and L, there's columns  in the middle without data but I need to select everything anyway. Thanks for your help

Comment: On lRowDT It is giving me =0 and on Rows.Count=1048576. But I don't know why.

Comment: Yes it worked by your way. Thanks mate. But I can't figurer it out why it doesn't work on my way.